# CloudFormation: Unresolved resource dependencies [Ec2Instance] in the Outputs block of the template

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a EC2 instance using cloudFormation template.
I have written below JSON for this and trying to upload json using  option in CloudFormation "Upload a template to Amazon S3".
But after uploading JSON I am getting error:

> Template validation error: Unresolved resource dependencies [Ec2Instance] in the Outputs block of the template.

Please advice what I am going wrong here?

```
{
    "Description": "Create an EC2 instance running the latest amazon Linux AMI.",
    "Parameters": {
        "KeyPair": {
            "Description": "The EC2 key Pair to allow SSH access to the instance",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "EC2Instance": {
            "Properties": {
                "ImageId": "ami-9d23aeea",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyPair"
                }
            },
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance"
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "InstanceId": {
            "Description": "The InstanceId of newly created EC2 instance",
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "Ec2Instance"
            }
        }
    },
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just made a typo. `EC2Instance` in your resources list and `Ec2Instance` in your outputs.

Comment: @tyron can you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: @vickey99 just click the gray "checkmark" that is displyed on the left side of the answer, right under the current number of votes.